# mysql new user access denied

Tags: mysql

Just started with mysql. I login with root and follow the online reference to create a new user:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'abc'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '111111';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'abc'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

then I quit and tried to login with the new user:

```
mysql --user=abc --password=111111 mysql
```

But got an error message:

> Access denied for user 'abc'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Did I missed something?

Comment: did you flush privileges??`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: 1) Add FLUSH PRIVILEGES after above 2 statement   and use 'localhost' or 'IP address' instead of '%' these work for me. hope this will help!!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Run this to work

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES
```

Once you have given the desired privileges for your user, you will need to FLUSH privileges in order to complete the setup and to make the new settings work. To do so, run this command within the SQL command prompt:

**[EDIT]**
If you want to connect from localhost also, you should create another account.

> It is necessary to have both accounts for 'user' to be able to connect
>   from anywhere as 'user'. Without the localhost account, the
>   anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by
>   mysql_install_db would take precedence when 'user' connects from the
>   local host. As a result, 'user'would be treated as an anonymous user.
>   The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more
>   specific Host column value than the 'user'@'%' account and thus comes
>   earlier in the user table sort order. )

FYI: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: hmm strange, this should work for creating "Super User" privileges . try logging with root user and see record is created or not!

Comment: Run select * from user where user='abc'. The record is there and the privileges are set to Y.

Comment: which version of mysql is that? It worked fine for me. follow this tutorial http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

Comment: I am using 5.1 on CentOS 6. The real strange thing is I can log in use abc from a remote windows machine. So the 'abc'@'%' does not allow localhost access? I also need a 'abc'@'localhost'?

Comment: ha! you need two accounts! From above link: "It is necessary to have both accounts for monty to be able to connect from anywhere as monty. Without the localhost account, the anonymous-user account for localhost that is created by mysql_install_db would take precedence when monty connects from the local host. As a result, monty would be treated as an anonymous user. The reason for this is that the anonymous-user account has a more specific Host column value than the 'monty'@'%' account and thus comes earlier in the user table sort order. )"

Comment: I did not know about needing 2 accounts. This clears up a lot of other ambiguous situations I've had of users not being able to log on. THanks!

Comment: FYI has been moved to [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-accounts.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/creating-accounts.html)

Comment: You don't really need two accounts, the difference between localhost and % is, the last one tells mysql that the user will connect from multiple hosts while the first one clearly says the user can only be logged from localhost. Also privileges granted using `GRANT` don't need you to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, because mysql reloads privileges tables automatically after you used `GRANT`.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was in password. After making it containing lesser amount of special characters, it started working.

Comment: I had the same experience

Answer (score 3):

Usualy this does the trick for me:

**Login to MySQL**

```
mysql -u root -p
```

**Create a MySQL user**

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'ip' IDENTIFIED BY '*password*';
```

**Allow full control to that user**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'username'@'ip';
```

**Reloading the privileges tables**

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Leaving the MySQL interface**

```
exit;
```

**Allow external acces from certain ip to port 3306**

```
sudo ufw allow from ip to any port 3306
```

**Go to the MySQL config file**

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

**Allow MySQL to look for connections externally**

Change:

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

To:

```
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0
```

In MySQL 8+ this line is not there to begin with, if so add it

**Restart MySQL**

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

I am however for some reason still experiencing the problem 'Acces denied for user', so if anyone could extend on my answer with a solution to my problem that would be amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Change host from '%' to 'localhost' worked for me.

However I do not know why.

Remember to 'flush privileges;'

I am using *mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.32-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1*

Answer (score -1):

If you run MySQL version 8 or higher using Docker image, you should downgrade the version. I tried MYSQL 5.7 image and then I was able to connect with a user(not root) from remote network.

Comment: Downgrading versions should not be a solution, especially to such an outdated one

Comment: while typically, I would agree with @Lunar, in this case, I can't because there are known compatibility issues with mysql 5.x servers and mysql 8.x clients ie https://serverfault.com/questions/1054823/how-do-i-deal-with-mysql-incompatibility-8-5 and a password hashing issue for which there will be no fix afaik. So for people who don't have control to upgrade the server, downgrading their client is the only option. Eric should not have been down-voted on this answer. In fact, using a docker image for such a reason is a sound idea in cases like this.

Answer (score -2):

This is it.

```
grant all privileges on *.* to `root`@`%` identified by 'chnagethepasswordhere'; 
flush privileges;
--helps to excute store procedure as root user

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE mbu4u.ratingProcedure TO 'root'@'ip.ip.ip.ip' identified by 'changepasswordheere';

GRANT ALL ON mbu4u.* TO root@'ip.ip.ip.ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'changepassword';
```

## dantheman @have a nice day!