# MySQL Error: SQL STATE[4200][1044] But All Privileges Granted

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

I am trying to make a PHP PDO connection to my database, however I am getting the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000] [1044] Access denied for user 'xxxx'@'%' to database 'xxxx'
```

I have tried several mysql users, who can access all other databases fine. I have also tried using root with super_priv enabled on the account.

What's weird, is if I try to connect to a different database but with the same user, it lets connects fine, however not to the database I wish to connect. So I checked the db privileges by using:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE Db = 'xxxx'\G;
```

This returned 3 rows, of which the third is the user account I wish to have access to the database.

```
*************************** 3. row ***************************
             Host: localhost
               Db: xxxx
             User: [xxxx]
      Select_priv: Y
      Insert_priv: Y
      Update_priv: Y
      Delete_priv: Y
      Create_priv: Y
        Drop_priv: Y
       Grant_priv: Y
  References_priv: Y
       Index_priv: Y
       Alter_priv: Y
Create_tmp_table_priv: Y
 Lock_tables_priv: Y
 Create_view_priv: Y
   Show_view_priv: Y
Create_routine_priv: Y
 Alter_routine_priv: Y
     Execute_priv: Y
       Event_priv: Y
     Trigger_priv: Y
```

I gave the user permissions with the following:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON xxxx.* TO '[xxxx]'@'xxxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxxx' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I have trawled through google, and tried every answer from stackoverflow and I can't seem to debug this issue! I always make sure I flush the privileges.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`'xxxx'@'%'` is not the same as `'xxxx'@'localhost'` or `'xxxx'@'IP'`.  If you are not connecting locally, then you will have different privileges than the localhost user.

Comment: When connecting to database A, the user has permissions, however when connecting to database B, the user does not. Both the permissions appear exactly the same in mysql though. There are two host records for each user, one for localhost and another for %. Neither seem to work.

Comment: Are you connecting remotely?  Show the exact GRANT (excluding the password) that you used to grant the privileges  to database B.  You keep replacing variables in your post but they might be hiding your error.

Comment: Yes, from another server in the same rack (same subnet). The code above shows the exact grant privileges on database B. If you have another sql query I can run, please show and I will run it.

Comment: No, it's not because we don't know if you're entering the correct IP/host.

Comment: Okay, the sql error shows access denied for user@'%'.. however there are two rows, one of them above, and the other exactly the same, except with % as the host.

Comment: I've never seen an access denied for @'%' before.  '%' should be the IP you are connecting from.

Answer (score 1):

As here ([mysql new user access denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098242/mysql-new-user-access-denied)) anonymous users in MySQL can cause this kind of permission denial. You should either create a user with the same name and machine field `localhost` or remove local anonymous account.

Comment: I have two users, one of them anonymous, if that's what % indicates, and the other as localhost.

Comment: Yes % indicates anonymous user. And if you have a ```%@localhost``` record in your users, you cannot connect to database. Since MySQL first evaluates the permissions according to hostname and then user name. To be more specific if you are connecting from a local machine it's access denied because MySQL first looks at your hostname and finds localhost then checks for a record ```xxxx@localhost``` if it cannot find it checks ```%@localhost``` and it has no permissions on database ```xxxx``` so it denies your access. If any of these records don't exist, It will look for ```xxxx@%```